# JRequest::get('post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW) has been deprecated, what is the working code now?

Tags: jinput, jrequest

I have tried every input to get it working, but nothing works for me.

This is the deprecated code

```
    $post = JRequest::get('post', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);

    list($title, $alias) = $this->_generateNewTitle($post['catid'], $post['alias'], $post['name']);
    $_POST['name']  = $title;
    $_POST['alias'] = $alias;
    $_POST['catid'] = 0;

    $this->_save();
```

I tried:

```
$post       = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('post', '','raw');
```

But sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: is `'post'` your variable name which raw value you want?

Comment: yes see source code:
https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/blob/K5.0/src/administrator/components/com_kunena/controllers/categories.php#L253

Comment: I suspect maybe something else is happening. The line you tried is what I use. The filters used by JInput are in libraries/joomla/filter/input.php. "RAW" is on about like 268.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a small mistake here. Have a look below:

> What you tried: `$post = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('post', '','raw');`

- Here, `'post'` must be the name parameter of the input field of which you want to fetch the value. Example below:

`$post = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('name', '','raw');`
Output: will give you the value of name input field.

In your case, you want to fetch the value of the entire post data in variable `$post` so you should try this:

`$post = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('jform','','raw');`

`jform` - I assume you are using joomla forms so by default the input field will come like `jform[name]`, `jform[catid]`,etc

Let us know on this

Comment: I tried this: but I still get:
Saving category 0 failed: Cannot save category: No name was provided!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('name', '', 'RAW');
```

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it by:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$post = $app->input->post->getArray();
```

Thnx for checking the issue.